Should there be increase in reputation for upvotes of a comment?
Should there be increase in reputation for upvotes of a comment?. The reason I am saying this is because, even if you can't answer the question fully, you atleast provide enough details for the answer to be clearly found. Plus it happened to me once, someone copied my exact same comment as mine and just added references and gained 100 reputation. Is there any workaround?

Well, I suppose you could have added the references as well to make a useful answer in the first place? (said somewhat tongue in cheek as someone who has been chided gently by mods for answering in comments rather than in the answer box below)

That would be a question for meta.se. I don't recommend going there with it, though. Such change won't pass. If you wanna get more rep. then answer.

@Mithoron As well, it would be a dupliate of many many questions there

No, comments should not grant reputation. Comments are temporary post notices and ideally all useful information should eventually be incorporated into a post. As well, many comments aren’t really “worth” anything, for example a “thanks” comment or a “+1”. If you are writing an answer in a comment, then that’s you doing something wrong, why not post it as an answer? If you can find enough details to answer the question, then use those details and answer the question.

There's no reputation gained or lost for votes on comments.  There is, however, a badge.  This is to encourage helpful participation by new members.
It is assumed we don't need to be "bribed" to make good comments.  The goal is for people to ask for clarification in comments in order to post a proper answer  The site is designed around the idea of making good answers.
An answer gets you ten points for every upvote.  That's the incentive to make an answer.
The logic of the site is, therefore, that the person who goes to the trouble of writing an answer (or even converting a comment to an answer) is the one who deserves the reputation point reward.
Answering in comments is very strongly discouraged, because then questions, from the system's point of view, are never answered.  We don't want unanswered questions.
Also:

someone copied my exact same comment as mine and just added references and gained 100 reputation

The lesson here is that, if you went to the trouble of writing an answer with references (not always required, but nice to have sometimes), you would deserve the points.
You did not do that.
However:
In general, people should first encourage the commenter to post an answer.  If they don't or decline to, maybe after 24 hours, it's fair to write an answer based on their comment.

if you can't answer the question fully

Then, unless someone else answers fully, a partial answer (which is not an opinion or a best guess !) is better than no answer.  But again, note that if someone then extends your answer in an answer of their own, they'll likely get more votes than you.
Doing the work to make a solid answer is what tends to get the most reputation.

Is there any workaround?

No.  The intent of the site designers is that this is the way they want the site to work.  In fairness, most long-term users do eventually get this.

What is the score threshold for no longer getting points for comment of votes? Is it a secret? it shouldn't be.

@Miss_Understands I don't think it's a secret, but it's my recollection that when I joined SE and was first able to comment, I got a point per comment.  I noticed this stopped and I vaguely recall reading this was the way the system operated somewhere, but cannot find the reference.  I think the problem with a lot of the site's mechanics is that, while somebody knows, it's not all written down in one place.  Sites like these can develop a huge number of (code) rules trying to cover all possible cases, and typically they're not well documented outside the site's code, if even there.

Slight correction: There are no rep points for comments -- which kinda makes sense, given that they're intended to be ephemeral. The proposal's been bandied about through the years, but the pros outweigh the cons.

@HDE226868 I've see that post, and a couple like it, but it does not tally with my recollection.  In any case, feel free to edit the post if you wish.

@StephenG   Edited as per my wish.
